# MapReduce - Reducing to Specify last colum

Tags: scala, mapreduce

I have this code:

```
 1.   var data = sc.textFile("test3.tsv")
 2.   var satir = data.map(line=> ((line.split("\t")(1),line.split("\t")(2)),(1,1)))
 3.   satir.reduce(((a,b),(c,k)) => k + k)
```

First and second works properly. What I want is by reducing (a,b), specify last '1'

For example, like this:

> ((a,b),(1,1))

But when I compile third one I get this error:

```
<console>:29: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int)
 required: String
       satir.reduce({ case ((a,b),(k,o)) =>o+o})
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you update this question with `test3.tsv` file content?

Answer (score 0):

When you reduce a value, the output value type must be the same as the input value type, you can use a `folding` method instead, because you can return another type with him.

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile("test3.tsv")
    .getLines
    .toList
    .map { line => 
        val value = line.split("\t")
        ((value(0), value(1)), (1,1))
    }
    .foldLeft(0)((response, tuple) => tuple._2._2 + tuple._2._2)
```

If you care to understand the theory behind this:

- [Fold explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))
- [A tutorial on the universality and
  expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/fold.pdf)
- [A Translation from Attribute Grammars to
  Catamorphisms](https://maartenfokkinga.github.io/utwente/mmf91c.pdf)